# Dishwasher Filling with Water Despite Supply Being Turned Off

Tags: plumbing, appliances, dishwasher

Our dishwasher has recently started filling with water between runs.  I had assumed that it was due to a faulty water inlet valve and was planning on replacing that.  However, I've closed the water supply to the dishwasher and it still seems to be filling with water.

The other possibility that I know of is for it to be backfill from the drain, however I'm almost certain it's not that as the drain line is air gapped from our disposal and it's happening even overnight when we haven't used the sink.

The only thing I can think of is that the gate valve is not closing all the way, it's fairly old and was very difficult to close, though it turns freely now.  I've tested turning on the dishwasher with the valve closed and it doesn't seem that any water is flowing, though I guess it could be a very small amount that's still accumulating when off.

Answer (score 2):

More than likely, it's the shutoff valve. They are known to corrode  after a number of years and not shut completely. Try disconnecting the line from the refrig with the valve shut as tight as possible and see what happens. Have a gallon jug handy to put the line in if it does, in fact, leak. If it is leaking, now would be the time to replace it. You would probably have to shut the water off to the whole house to do this. It's normally a fairly easy job to do.

Comment: Shutting off the water to the whole house - once a year is good. It keeps the valve/gate movable, and won't be solid when comes the emergency that necessitates it being turned off. Same could actually go for all shut-off valves.